# knockout js update dirty flag when any property changes using with ko.mapping

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to add a dirty flag to my knockout js model (I expected it to be an easy task), the flag will update when any property is altered.

I completed some research prior to posting here and found most answers point to [this blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html) there is also a fiddle linked to the post, which I have tried to follow, but without success.

I also tried using jquery to and listened for when an input or select element changed, but that fired onpage load when the inputs were being populated, so the flag would always be set as dirty.

The difference between my model and the example is I use Auto mapper

In the example it shows `Item` has a `dirty` flag. How would I go about replicating this when using auto mapper? (I have added my json model in case it helps to offer a "best" solution)

**the JS from the example**

```
ko.dirtyFlag = function(root, isInitiallyDirty) {
var result = function() {},
    _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root)),
    _isInitiallyDirty = ko.observable(isInitiallyDirty);

result.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
    return _isInitiallyDirty() || _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
});

result.reset = function() {
    _initialState(ko.toJSON(root));
    _isInitiallyDirty(false);
};

return result;
};

function Item(id, name) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(this);
}

var ViewModel = function(items) {
this.items = ko.observableArray([
    new Item(1, "one"),
    new Item(2, "two"),
    new Item(3, "three")
]);

this.save = function() {
    alert("Sending changes to server: " + ko.toJSON(this.dirtyItems));  
};

this.dirtyItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
        return item.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
    });
}, this);

this.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.dirtyItems().length > 0;
}, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**my json object**

```
{"PropertyID":0,"BulletPoints":["test 1","test 2","test 3"],"BriefDescription":"Some test desc","TakeOnAppointmentDate":"0017-03-02T12:05:00","Rooms":null,"TenureLengthOfLease":10,"TenureLengthOfService":10,"GroundCharges":11.0,"Directions":"go here then there","KeyHolderName":"Name","KeyHolderReference":"very nice","IsDisplayToPublic":true,"UploadToRightMove":false,"UploadToOnTheMarkert":false,"UploadToPrimeLocation":false,"RightMoveCost":1000.0,"EpcCost":100.0,"FloorPlanCost":2.0,"RoomIdentifier":null,"CoverIdentifier":null,"CoverPath":null,"PreviewUrl":null,"EpcReportPdf":null,"FloorPlan1":null,"FloorPlan2":null,"DisplayFrom":185.000,"DisplayTo":200.000,"SelectedSalePriceOptionId":3,"IsHidden":null,"AddressLine1":null,"NumberOfBedrooms":5,"NumberOfBathrooms":3,"NumberOfReceptionrooms":2,"Tenures":[{"Id":1,"Description":"Freehold"},{"Id":2,"Description":"LeaseHold"}],"SelectedTenureId":2,"ViewingInstructions":[{"Id":1,"Description":"Accompanied viewings with prior notice"},{"Id":2,"Description":"Vacant property"},{"Id":3,"Description":"Vendor to do viewings"}],"SelectedViewingInstructionId":2,"SaleStates":[{"Id":1,"Description":"For Sale"},{"Id":2,"Description":"Sold"},{"Id":3,"Description":"SSTC"},{"Id":4,"Description":"To Let"}],"SelectedSaleStateId":2,"UnderOffers":[{"Id":0,"Description":"No"},{"Id":1,"Description":"Yes"}],"SelectedUnderOfferId":1,"SalePriceOptions":[{"Id":1,"Description":"Asking Price"},{"Id":2,"Description":"Guide Price"},{"Id":3,"Description":"Offers Over"},{"Id":4,"Description":"In the region of"},{"Id":5,"Description":"Auction guide"}],"BlobItems":[]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the most basic implementation all you need for a global dirty flag is three things

- State variable (boolean flag) to hold dirty status
- Computed property that uses ko.toJS or ko.toJSON on the root object
- Subscription function to update the state variable when the computed property changes

If your viewmodel is built with ko.mapping it might look something like this:

```
var viewModel = function(jsonData){
  var self = this;

  ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData, {}, this);

  self.isDirty = ko.observable(false);
  self.toJS = ko.computed(function(){
    return ko.toJS(self);
  });
  self.toJS.subscribe(function(value){
    self.isDirty(true);
  });
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/1o4sbkaz/)

After that you can add extra complexity to store the initial toJS() result and compare it against new values to see if the data really has changed or if it was just set back to the same data.

As the blog goes on to say though, it's not the best way to do it. Any change will cause the computed to recalculate by traversing the entire tree of observables in your viewmodel which can get costly.

Here's another version I was using for a while that only evaluates the first time a change is made, and then just returns dirty=true afterward. I'm pretty sure I got this one from Ryan Niemeyer as well, but I can't remember where. I don't see one quite like it on the blog you referenced.

```
var viewModel = function(jsonData){
  var self = this;

  ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData, {}, this);

  this.dirtyCheck = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      if (!self.isDirty){ //property doesn't exist yet
        var json = ko.toJSON(self); //trigger a subscription to all observable properties.
      } else {
        self.isDirty(true); //If this is being evaluated then by definition something has changed.
      }
      return;
    }
  });
  this.isDirty = ko.observable(false); //only add the property after the computed has been initialized
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. this line `self.toJS = ko.computed(()=>{
    return ko.toJS(self);
  });` needed to be changed to `self.toJS = ko.computed(function(){
                return ko.toJS(self);
            }, this);` to get it to work for me. I'd be interested to know what the difference is and why the change was required (when you have shown it working in jsfiddle)

Comment: Whoops I thought I caught all of those, but I missed that one. It's an ecma script 6 arrow function which probably isn't supported in the version of javascript you're using.